# Multivariate Emperical CDF

Tags: matlab

How can I compute a multivariate emperical CDF?  Is there anything in Matlab, or perhaps an approach that can give me similar output as `ecdf` but as an input uses a matrix instead of a vector.

Appreciate any input.

Basically would like something like this:

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/EmpiricalDistribution.html

Comment: @fpe mvn assumes normality, I want emperical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, to provide an official answer (based on our comment conversation):

Use hist3 to get the emprical pdf, and then do a 2D cumsum (I'm not sure this is built in, but you could write your own) to sum across the pdf and create a 2D cdf. Each entry in the cdf matrix is the sum of all values of lesser row and column index in the pdf matrix.

Answer (score -1):

If *ecdf* works for what you need, and you only need matrix functionality, you can try vectorizing the input to *ecdf* and then reshaping the output.

```
y = rand(100); % replace this with your actual code...
f = ecdf(y(:)); % pass in the vectorized version of y
f = reshape(f, size(y)); % Reshape output
```

Comment: I need `ecdf` to take on two seperate variables and show me the distribution based on these two variables.  Look at `hist3`.  Not sure how this would work?

Comment: Well, the heights coming out of hist3 represent the discretized pdf. By performing a 2D cumsum (each cell in the matrix gets the sum of all values of lesser row and column), you will have a 2D cdf. Would that work for what you need?